# WP_Query loop doen't work with my custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, loop

My loop don't display my all relevant posts, It's should display the all posts which started w/specific letter (if it " " then it's should display the all posts sorted by popularity) what's wrong w/it?

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 if ($first_letter!=' ') { $args = array (
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
        'term' => $term->name,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged); }
    else {$args = array (
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
        'term' => $term->name,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'showposts' => 160,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged); }

 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 $mam_global_where = ''; // Turn off filter
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $in_this_row = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ($first_letter!=' '&&$first_letter!='') { $first_letter = strtoupper(substr(apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title),0,1));}
        if ($first_letter != $curr_letter) {
            if (++$post_count > 1) { end_prev_letter(); }
            start_new_letter($first_letter);
            $curr_letter = $first_letter;
            }
        if (++$in_this_row > $posts_per_row) {
            end_prev_row();
            start_new_row();
            ++$in_this_row; // Account for this first post
            } ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel=.....</a>   
    </div> <!--end #post-->
    <?php }
 end_prev_letter();
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what part of this code doesn't work? Also, there are several functions used by that code that you have not posted. That makes this impossible to test and debug accurately.

Comment: What @s_ha_dum said. Please describe what *works* and what *doesn't work*. What did you do to **debug**? Did you pare your code down to *just* the taxonomy parameters, in order to eliminate any other potential issues?

Answer (score 1):

Your `taxonomy` and `term` arguments are incorrect. The preferred method is via `tax_query`

```
$args = array(
    // ... other args
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term->name
        )
    )
);
```

Please see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all valid arguments and their correct formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Milo, I tried your change and it's help :(
Well, this code it's part of my taxonomy.php and all I want to do is to display and list of my posts by the first letter. here you can find it: http://www.bmobile.co.il/ (and choose the taxonomy). thanks for your support!!!!